# Why do I get a Boot timeout error (Error R10) when running my app on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, timeout

I have a Java app that I deployed on Heroku. The deployment works like a charm, no errors or warnings and the app starts working. However, after some time, I get the following error:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

I do not get any error when I am running my app locally.

*FYI:* this app periodically checks whether or not there are changes made to a table in a postgresql database and, if so, updates another table in that same database (as far as I can see not really relevant to my problem, but here you go).

Here is the log:

```
2019-02-12T19:37:15.444651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=24637 -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.name.numbersbackend.Main`
2019-02-12T19:37:18.657701+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2019-02-12T19:37:18.660650+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2019-02-12T19:37:35.580329+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:37:51.105807+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:38:06.683974+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:38:22.198062+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:38:37.792613+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:38:45.489753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-02-12T19:38:45.489753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-02-12T19:38:45.663859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-02-12T19:38:45.682773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-02-12T19:38:45.766843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-02-12T19:38:48.871480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=39010 -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.name.numbersbackend.Main`
2019-02-12T19:38:51.074950+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2019-02-12T19:38:51.077995+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2019-02-12T19:39:07.724633+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:39:23.250203+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:39:38.760492+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:39:54.313859+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:40:09.881207+00:00 app[web.1]: .
2019-02-12T19:40:19.374407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-02-12T19:40:19.187236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-02-12T19:40:19.187351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-02-12T19:40:19.354497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

*FYI:* The line `2019-02-12T19:39:38.760492+00:00 app[web.1]: .` (and lines like this) contains some temporary output from my app to show that it is actually doing something. For each of these lines, the program is checking if there are changes to the table and if so, if it needs to take action (if it does need to take action, the output of the app is more meaningful).

As you can see, the app is starting alright, working for some time, then crashes and even restarts. However, at some point it stops working entirely.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.name.app.backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.myname</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-lib</artifactId>
            <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

...and my Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* nl.limakajo.numbersbackend.Main
```

After a lot of Googling and browsing on SO, I have not found a solution.

Comment: This error means it's been more than 90 seconds since Heroku started your app, and when it binds to $PORT. When you run `heroku ps:restart`, how long does it usually take before the app starts receiving web requests? What does the `nl.limakajo.numbersbackend.Main` class do before binding to a port?

Comment: The app doesn't do too much before it connects to the web. At the moment it connects every 15 seconds (note to self: this should be less frequent).

Comment: every 15 seconds it makes an outbound connection? But I'm referring to when it binds to the $PORT locally. It should do this once immediately when the app starts up. Otherwise, it should not be a `web:` process.

Comment: Perhaps it should not be a `web:` process then. What the app does (as described) is checking a postgresql database and updating a table in that database (depending on the data in said database). What do you suggest?

Comment: Change `web:` to `worker:` or something. Then redeploy, and run `heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want this process to run in the background an not handle web requests. If that's the case, you don't want to use `web:` in your `Procfile`. On Heroku, the `web` process is treated specially: it is assigned a `PORT` env var, which must be bound to in the first 90 seconds after launch.

I recommend changing your `Procfile` to:

```
worker: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* nl.limakajo.numbersbackend.Main
```